# Unsure of how to apply arguments to a constructor [Haskell & CodeWorld API]

Tags: haskell

**Preface:**

I have this function in Haskell within the CodeWorld API.

```
shapeToPic :: Shape -> Picture
```

.hs file containing the data type definitions:

```
module Shape where

import CodeWorld (Point)

data Shape = Rectangle Side Side
           | Ellipse   Side Side
           | Polygon   [Point]
           | Line      Point Point
  deriving (Show)

data Tool = RectangleTool (Maybe Point)
          | EllipseTool   (Maybe Point)
          | LineTool      (Maybe Point)
          | PolygonTool   [Point]
  deriving (Show)

toolKeyMap :: [(String, Tool)]
toolKeyMap = [
  ("R", RectangleTool Nothing),
  ("E", EllipseTool Nothing),
  ("P", PolygonTool []),
  ("L", LineTool Nothing)
  ]

type Side = Double
```

**Main:**

I want to define each of those patterns (Rectangle, Ellipse etc.) which are required to define the data type "Shape".

Now my current code consists of this

```
shapeToPic :: Shape -> Picture
shapeToPic Rectangle = (translated (-3) 6  (solidRectangle 4 4))
shapeToPic Ellipse = colored red (translated 0 (-1.5) (solidCircle 8))
shapeToPic Polygon = colored blue (translated 0 (-1.5) (solidPolygon [4,2]))
shapeToPic Line = c
```

And I get an error saying that:

```
The constructor Rectangle' should have 2 arguments, but has been given none
      In the pattern: Rectangle
      In an equation for shapeToPic':
          shapeToPic Rectangle = (translated (- 3) 6 (solidRectangle 4 4))
```

Now I am not sure how to give the constructor **Rectangle** two arguments and I'm not sure what is meant by "Side Side" in the Rectangle data type definition. By applying "solidRectangle 4 4" I would have thought it would fulfill the 2 sides requirement. Now I am confused.

Would appreciate the help.

Comment: The data definition for side is invalid, are you sure that's what it looks like?

Comment: @MauriceWillis Please double-check that other .hs file. Preferably, just copy and paste rather than re-typing from memory.

Comment: You should use `shapeToPic (Rectangle side1 side2) = ...` using `size1`, `side2` as needed. Similarly for other cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't match *just* the constructor; you need to match its arguments as well:

```
shapeToPic (Rectangle x y) = (translated (-3) 6  (solidRectangle 4 4))
```

If you don't care about the actual `x` and `y` values, you can replace them with `_`:

```
shapeToPic (Rectangle _ _) = (translated (-3) 6  (solidRectangle 4 4))
```

The two values are (likely) intended to be the length and width of the value, and you probably want to preserve them, assuming `solidRectangle` is a function that returns a new `Rectangle` value.

```
    shapeToPic (Rectangle x y) = (translated (-3) 6  (solidRectangle x y))
```

Or, you might just want to reuse the original value:

```
shapeToPic (Rectangle x y) = translated (-3) 6 (Rectangle x y)
```

or

```
shapeToPic r@(Rectangle _ _) = translated (-3) 6 r
```